# How to iterate numbers to a limit by addition

Tags: c#, iteration, sequences

Here is the code I have right now:

```
for(int i=0; i< 35; ++i)
{
    int a = 1;
    a+=1;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

The output is:

> 2
>   2
>   2
>   ...

and so on, until the loop terminates.

What I want to do is add the previous two numbers to make the nest number then so on all the way to 34.

Comment: If you are trying to iterate to 34, why did you write 55 in the loop condition?

Comment: please post your entire code. Especially the part where you add the numbers up. Do you save the result in a variable? and what is `a` ?

Comment: For starters, are you sure you are not mixing up `34`and `55`? Secondly, you can easily calculate the sum of 1 to N as `(N/2)*N` for odd N or `((N+1)/2)*N` for even N.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight extra level of complexity?

Comment: This almost seems like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/369311). Either that, or you are asking how a [for-loop works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop).

Comment: This is for a calculator project.

Comment: Thanks to a comment you made on an answer, it turns out you want code for the **Fibonacci sequence**. There must be millions of code examples for that on the net, and the code you provided does not even come close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can achieve what you want:

```
//Initializing the elements
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = 1;

Console.WriteLine(a); //Typing the 0'th element
Console.WriteLine(b); //Typing the first element

for(;c <= 34; c = a + b) {
    Console.WriteLine(c); //Typing the actual element
    a = b;
    b = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean count to some number by adding other and using this as what? Escape condition? Just as a constant in addition?

as escape condition:

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    static private int a = 0;
    static private int i = 0;
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            a += i;
            if (a == 595) break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

as a constant in addition:

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    static private int a = 0;
    static private int i = 0;
    static private int d = 1;
    public static void Main()
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 34; i++){
            a += d;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}
```

Both seem highly illogical to use tho :/

**EDIT:** Your question is now different from what you told before :D

You are wondering why is a not getting larger than 2? Because you initialize it each step of for loop. You need to move initialization out of the scope of for. Try this:

```
using System;
public class Program
{
    static private int a = 0;
    static private int i = 0;
    static private int d = 1;
    public static void Main()
    {
        int a = 1;
        for(int i=0; i< 34; ++i)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(a);   
            a+=1;

            }
    }
}
```

I understand you need numbers from 1 to 34. So you can't start with 1, immediately increment by 1 and then write it cause it will be 2. Write first, then increment.

Or you can start with 0 then you can increment first. But adjust end condition as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a new variable `a` with each iteration and then add 1 to it. Since the initial value of `a` is 1, you calculate `1+1` with each iteration. Step through the code in a debugger to see what I mean.

Move the declaration out of the loop and you should see your desired output:

```
int a = 1;
for(int i=0; i< 35; ++i)
{
    a+=1;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

There are tons of tutorials how you can print out the fibonacci sequence, for example with two nested for-loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
        var temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp + b;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Example taken from [dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/fibonacci)  (albeit slightly edited by me).

Comment: Thanks for answering but this only counts the numbers from 2 to 36. it doesn't add the two previous numbers like the Fibonnaci sequence

Comment: @IkechukwuNwakanma: I completly missed that you wanted to print out the fibonacci sequence. I have updated my answer.